# Palindrome parser logic error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that parses through an input and determines whether or not it is a palindrome. Pasted below is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Gets a message and shift amount and caesar shifts the message by the desired amount. Displays the enciphered message.
public class RobustPalChecker{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      //declare variables
      char current, currentReverse;
      int msgInt;
      String msg, msgReverse;
      StringBuffer sbMsg, newMsg;

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      //get message
      System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
      msg = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      //msgReverse = new StringBuffer(msg).reverse().toString();  
      System.out.println(msg);
      //System.out.println("= " + msgReverse);
      //get first and last index of string to check if it's a palindrome

      for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
         current = msg.charAt(i);          
         if(Character.isLetter(current) == false){
            sbMsg = new StringBuffer(msg);
            newMsg = sbMsg.deleteCharAt(i); 
            msgReverse = new StringBuffer(newMsg).reverse().toString();
         }
      }  


      if(newMsg.equals(msgReverse)) {
                  System.out.println("It's a palindrome");
      }else {
                  System.out.println("It's not a palindrome");
      }   
   }
}
```

Ignore comments as some of them don't apply and I have not cleaned it up yet. The line of code that I'm pretty sure is causing the error is the isLetter line. The goal of that loop is to find any character that is not a letter and just delete it, and that includes whitespace. That last if statement is the one that actually compares the reversed string and regular string. Now the output that the last if statement is giving me when I try to compile is "variable newMsg might not have been initialized" and the same for msgReverse, but that's not my main question.
**My main question is: Is my logic here correct or incorrect?**

Also, if you need me to rephrase the question, I can do that as I understand this might be hard to follow, I'm just panicking a little.

Comment: `Ignore comments as some of them don't apply and I have not cleaned it up yet.` ... do you expect us to clean up the code for you?

Comment: *My main question is: Is my logic here correct or incorrect?*...did you execute the above code once?

Comment: `if(newMsg.equals(msgReverse))` compares a string to a stringbuffer - are you sure that's what you want to do ?

Comment: ??? I'm not trying to sound like an asshole or anything, but I'm asking for help on my logic, not my messy code. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?  Can you let us know what the exact problem is?

Comment: I have executed the above code without the last if statement and it gives me the string reversed, but it doesn't seem to delete the punctuation or whitespace.

Comment: @alfasin I was under the impression that .toString would make it a string and not a buffer.

Comment: But you're not calling toString, you're doing `newMsg.equals`

Comment: Further, the logic to create `msgReverse` is executed only if the condition in the `if` evaluates to `true` - when it's not `true` this parameter will not get initialized. That's probably the reason you're getting a compilation error. Try reading the errors the compiler gives you, usually it's not difficult to understand what the compiler says.

Comment: @alfasin Sorry, I should've clarified. I meant that I thought this line: msgReverse = new StringBuffer(newMsg).reverse().toString(); Would make msgReverse a string.

Comment: And does it get executed  ? ;)

Comment: logic is ok, but code is messy.

Comment: @alfasin So I should be reversing before the loop, yeah?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Since you're reversing the string in one line of code, why do you need to iterate the characters ?

Comment: Ahh, ok. That makes sense. I guess that was my actual question. My apologies it took this long.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems fine, but since code is not at all upto the mark its difficult to verify. I have written code in english commented format, if you are able to fill in the blanks all will fall in place.

Let's breakdown the problem in two sections :

1. Remove unwanted characters from string
2. Check if string returned from step1 is a pallindrome.

Create two functions :

```
String cleanUp(String arg){
  //create a stringbuffer from arg
  //start for loop
    //delete unwanted chars from stringbuffer
  //end loop
  //make string from stringbuffer and return
}

boolean pallindrome(String arg){
  //create a new string from arg reverse
  //return true if reversed string and arg are same
}
```

Now call these functions from your main method.

Comment: Ok I see. I am still relatively new to this and I'm not sure how to call upon the functions from the main method, but I'm sure I can figure it out. Just to clarify, the deletion of characters and the comparison of strings should be two separate entities in order for my code to work?

Comment: yep, deletion and comparison are different parts of program.